# FetchError: invalid json response body GraphQL

Tags: node.js, json, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using `@apollo/datasource-rest` to wrap a 3rd party API. The endpoint I'm trying to hit checks if an email is already in use or not. If the email is in use the response looks like this

```
    "body": "True",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "contentType": "application/json",
```

If the email is not in use the api returns a 404 like this

```
    "body": "",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "statusDescription": "Resource not found",
```

The problem is the `express.json()` or `bodyParser.json()` middleware throws an error because `"True"` is not valid JSON and it is only getting parsed as json because the 3rd party API is sending back a response header of `"Content-Type": "application/json"`.

Is there a way to change the content type of the response before it hits the `express.json()` or `bodyParser.json()` middleware

Here is my Apollo Express Server

```js
const main = async () => {
  const app = express()
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app)
  const port = process.env.PORT

  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ resolvers, typeDefs })

  // Set up Apollo Server
  const server = new ApolloServer<MyContext>({
    schema,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
  })

  await server.start()

  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    cors<cors.CorsRequest>({
      origin: '*',
    }),
    json(),
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: async ({ req, res }) => {
        return {
          req,
          res,
          datasources: {
            someAPI: new SomeAPI(),
          },
        }
      },
    }),
  )

  await new Promise<void>((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port }, resolve))
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${port}/graphql`)
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Comment: You're right that the 3rd party API is lying about its response being JSON, now what to do about it? Please show the code where you're using `@apollo/datasource-rest` and where you're querying the 3rd party API.